# Irrlicht Gui mouse will not click buttons

Tags: c++, user-interface, button, irrlicht

I'm making my first game in Irrlicht (C++), an RTS with mouse control

and when you select a tile (by clicking on it) it lights up and some gui button appear on the screen (not in a gui window mind you, I like it this way):

http://i1139.photobucket.com/albums/n549/Adam_Halley-Prinable/Untitled2.png

However, since i switched to mouse control, the buttons wont register my mouse clicks. The click goes straight through the button and selects the tile behind instead:

http://i1139.photobucket.com/albums/n549/Adam_Halley-Prinable/Untitled3.png

Is there a way I can say "Buttons get top priority for clicks"?
I'm using MyEventReceiver, which i've messed around with to accept mouse clicks and that.

Thanks a bunch :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone else has the same problem, ill tell you how I solved it :)

Go through the MyEventReceiver.h and get rid of all the "return true;"'s in the mouse section.

Don't ask me why, but it works, and appears to have no side effects. Make sure you leave the "return false;" at the end of the section there.

Answer (score 0):

Your event receiver fires before the GUI gets access to the event, if you want to pass it to the GUI then you can do this by manually posting it to the GUIEnvironment in your event receiver.

```
if (guienv->postEventFromUser(event)) 
    return true; // abort because the gui wanted it

// .. pick nodes

// possibly post event to scene manager

return true; // remember to return true so gui/smgr don't get the event again
```

Comment: That sounds like it should work, but i'm just having a little scope trouble. The event reciever doesnt know what guienv is yet... hmm.. maybe I could just plonk the guienv definition in there somewhere...

Comment: This almost worked, but the guienv was just not in scope. Thanks though